# must re-install WAMP, but want to save my MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

After installing a newer version of WAMP both WAMP-Installations won't start anymore. I can't figure out why and don't want to waste more time with it as I have to work on a project.

I would like to uninstall WAMP and reinstall again. How can I save all MySQL-Databases? PHPMyAdmin won't start. I see the database data seems to be in folder C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data

Will it work if I just copy that folder, uninstall, reinstall WAMP and copy all data back from that folder?

Of course I would also copy all data from C:\wamp\www before uninstalling WAMP.

Any help is appreciated.

Milan

Answer (score 0):

Take backup of `/var/lib/mysql/<your database>`
Reinstall WAMP
Restore `<your database>` back to `/var/lib/mysql`
Change ownership & group to `mysql` by `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/`
Start `MySQL`

Comment: The `W` in WAMPServer stands for Windows